# (Do) you look forward to...?

Tags: difference, idiomatic-language

*(Do) You look forward to getting back to work?*

In speech would there be any difference between adding *do* or not? If you omit it could it indicate that the speaker is more certain that he does look forward to it than if you include it? Or is the meaning the same? I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: The auxiliary "do" is what a question in the simple present. Only in casual speech do you omit it. [Do] you understand?

Comment: @Lambie, You know, you're right!

Answer (score 1):

> Do you look forward to getting back to work?

Is always a simple question.

> You look forward to getting back to work?

As Lambie says in their comment is a casual, spoken way of asking the same question, but it also depends on the way it is spoken. If stress is placed on the word *forward* it can be interpreted as expressing doubt or incredulity. The speaker is questioning a previous statement.

> A. I'm looking forward to getting back to work.
> B. You look *forward* to getting back to work?  .. I don't believe you.

Note: Omitting the question mark converts the second version into a statement of fact.